# How to install jsonnet on conda

Tags: python, conda, allennlp, jsonnet

I am installing allennlp and it has quite a lot of dependencies. Everything is installing fine but the installalation of Jsonnet is failing.

I tried installing jsonnet using
`pip install jsonnet` manually but that isn't working either.

Comment: try !pip install jsonnet

Comment: It was working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge jsonnet
```